# Need to do search

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
DataTable dtble = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Any(row => row.Field<String>("Course") == "Math")
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

I would like the records to be filtered where `Course` contains `"Math"`.  I tried to use `.Any()` but it did not work.

To clarify, if Course has 12XMath123 I should still return a record as it contains "Math". Usig the Where cause will only return records where it is "Math" and not where it Contains "Math"

Comment: With.Any() you find out whether there is one or more elements that satisfy your condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `Where()` instead of `Any()`. This works for me:

```
DataTable dtble = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(row => row.Field<String>("Course") == "Math")
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

As per comment, you could try `StartsWith()` or `EndsWith()` or `Contains()`. Ex:

```
DataTable dtble = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(row => row.Field<String>("Course").Contains("Math"))
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Kaf, I like to have it where Course Contains "Math" meaning it can be like "Math123" and it will not be returned in what is above.

Comment: Thanks Kaf, but what happens if it is like 1123Math122. I still need it to return a value

Comment: Best would be `Contains()` for your situation. Answer updated. You could consider changing `filed value and text into same case` if you are searching case independently.

Answer (score 1):

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx) for basic Linq examples. But you're looking for Where, which returns a group of values that match the given predicate. Any returns a bool indicating whether any elements match a given predicate.

```
var dtble = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Course") == "Math")
              .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: You're thinking of `Where`. `Select` will perform a projection, and you'll end up with all `bool`s.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Where rather than Any, and when comparing strings with Linq, you are better suited to use the .Equals method. You should also Trim() whitespace and use .Lower or .Upper to get consistent casing.

```
DataTable dtble = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("Course")
                    .Trim().Lower().Equals("math")
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```